# Can not boot Ubuntu 16.04 from flash drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, bootloader

I created Ubuntu bootloader on flash drive and when I start Ubuntu from it then I get only terminal with such a message:

```
 Erst: can not request [mem 0xbd2e903f - 0xbd2eb03e] for ERST

No caching mode page found

Assuming drive cache: write through

ata 10.00: Exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen

Failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE

status: {DRDY}
```

[image]

What the reason of this issue and how to fix it? Could it be features of my hardware?

P.S. On another desktop I can boot from this flash drive normally.

Comment: how did you create (which software) the bootable on usb?

Comment: UNetbootin as always

Comment: If your USB device has GPS partition table and PC has msdos/MBR/BIOS partition table, it will never boot. GPT only works on Uefi hardware. Unetbootin doesn't work well with GPT formatted disks.

Comment: Hmm, is solution to use LinuxLive USB Creator instead of unetbootin?